# Finding the angle between lines represented by a homogenous equation

Tags: calculus, geometry, coordinate-systems

I am trying to find angle between two lines represented by the following homogeneous equation: $$ 7x^2 + 4xy + 4y^2 = 0.$$

I tried to use the standard formula $$ \theta = \arctan \left(\frac{2 \sqrt {h^2 - ab}}{a + b}\right),$$ but here $h^2 - ab$ is negative and I cannot find the angle.

Is there any other method to find the angle between them?

Comment: Related :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248132/transformation-of-axes-rotation?

Comment: That post is now deleted. :) This is my actual question. ( And looks easier too ) @labbhattacharjee

Comment: So, ain't anyone giving answers?

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/ImaginaryAngle.shtml

Comment: the site somehow defines my problem but i could not get it. Can you please explain it in a clear way @labbhattacharjee . Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some  restless searching. I found out the answer.

Actually the equation i posted does not represent pair of straight line.

For  a homogeneous equation to be a pair of straight line (passing through origin), $ h^2 > ab$ is a must